# Excel IF statement

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to look at column E and if it is >0 put a 1 UNLESS column D has a value. If column D has a value, I would like to copy the contents of column D. I was thinking the following formula would work, but it is giving me an error:

```
=IF(E2>0,1) OR IF(D2>0,D2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you don't say what you want to happen if E is not > 0, but with that caveat:

```
=IF(E2>0, IF(D2>0, D2, 1), SOMETHING)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will more beneficial for you. Because if cell E2 or D2 has value less then 0, then it will not work.

```
=IF((LEN(E2))>0,IF((LEN(D2))>0,D2,""),"Your Text Here")
```